# making cache using cache=True does not work in Scanpy

Tags: caching, oserror, scanpy

`Hi, I my code does work if I use cache=False

WT = sc.read_10x_mtx('/Users/sandb/OneDrive/UCB/result/scRNAseq/1strun/WT',
var_names='gene_symbols', cache=False)

but when I change chache=True

WT = sc.read_10x_mtx('/Users/sandb/OneDrive/UCB/result/scRNAseq/1strun/WT',
var_names='gene_symbols', cache=True)

I have OS error.
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '-Users-sandb-OneDrive-UCB-result-scRNAseq-1strun-WT-matrix.h5ad', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 13, o_flags = 302

Is there anyway to fix it?

I could not fix for a week...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I see is, it tries to create the file with the name: '-Users-sandb-OneDrive-UCB-result-scRNAseq-1strun-WT-matrix.h5ad' which starts with '-'. I don't know which os you are using and how the library creates files but, for instance, `touch -my_file.txt` wont work with bash. It will complain `touch: invalid option` because whatever comes after `-` is an option or argument.

All in all, this seems to be a bug you have hit. It appears Scanpy takes the path you give it, replaces all occurrences of '/' with '-' to make the file name for the cache file however it should skip the initial '/'. Which it does not.

I cannot reproduce your problem however you can try giving the prefix parameter to read_10x_mtx as

```
WT = sc.read_10x_mtx('/Users/sandb/OneDrive/UCB/result/scRNAseq/1strun/WT', var_names='gene_symbols', cache=True, prefix='SomePref')
```

So that your cache file name does not start with '-'.

Comment: Thanks! I solved. I used OneDrive and it was the problem. Now I copied the file in my C drive and it works fine. Thank you though!